# Deep Generative Networks Probability of "Success"

Tags: deep-learning, generative-adversarial-networks, autoencoders

I have built various "successful" GANs or VAEs that can generate realistic images reliably, but in either case the generative step is sampling a latent feature vector from some distribution and running it through a generator/decoder $G(x) \  s.t. \  x \sim \mathbb{D} $.

Generally $\mathbb{D}$ has a continuous domain (normally distributed is a common choice), and $G(x)$ is a continuous and at-least singly differential function (by construction so it could be optimized with a gradient scheme).

Now assume we have 2 images $y_1, y_2$ generated by $x_1, x_2 \sim \mathbb{D}$ and that shortest path from $x_1$ to $x_2$ is also in $\mathbb{D}$'s domain. Crawling along this path, we get a continuous path from $y_1$ to $y_2$ in image space. Wouldnt you assume along this continuous transformation that the images would be a "Garbage" as they are essentially a fusion of $y_1, y_2,$ and $\{y_k\}_k$ where $\{y_k\}_k$ describes a set of "succesful" stops along the way? 
 --Especially in cases of single mode distributions (like normal) where all $x$ on the path must have higher likelihood than atleast one of the paths endpoints.

Trying to summarize my point, how do continuous generative models not with high probability produce garbage when given any 2 "succesful" images, there probably is a high range of "garbage" examples along a path between them in image space?

Note: by "succesful" i mean the generated image could be considered a draw from the true distribution you are trying to capture by the generator, and by "garbage" i mean ones that are obviously not.

Comment: "Wouldnt you assume along this continuous transformation that the images would be a "Garbage" as they are essentially a fusion" - why do you think they would be a fusion? Also, what do you exactly mean by "Crawling along this path". The VAE is trained to learn the distribution that resembles the training dataset, this is likely why the results are acceptable, if this is what you mean.

Comment: @nbro by definition it is a continuous path from $y_1$, and $y_2$, which is where i get the "fusion"... and i get your point, that is the training objective, but im saying by design of the gen. Example: imagine a gen training on a multiclass dataset, intuitively you expect domain($\mathbb{D}$) to be pseudo-partioned into realms where certain clusters generate different classes. Now follow a line from one class to another, eventually youll hit a boundary where you see images that are questionably one or the other, probably producing 'garbage'

Comment: To be sure, $\mathbb{D}$ is the latent space and $x_1$ and $x_2$ are two latent variables (or are they the input examples, that is, other images)?

Comment: yes thats right. it is the latent space.